# Dependency injection failed when two different packages are interlinked in spring

Tags: java, spring

I am not able to autowire when field which exists in different package is autowired.

My code looks like this

Injecting class

```
package com.vmware.vchs.networkservice.extensions.http
@Component
public class HttpServiceClient implements ContextAware
{
@Autowired
JMXAgent jMXAgent;
....
};
```

Injected class

```
package com.vmware.vchs.networkservice.monitoring;

@Component
public class JMXAgent {
};
```

My component scan xml file looks like this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
   xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
   xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
   xmlns:bean="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
   xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd"

<context:property-placeholder 
    location="classpath:environment.properties" 
    ignore-unresolvable="false"/>

<bean:component-scan base-package="com.vmware.vchs.networkservice"/>
</beans>
```

The error is

```
Exception in thread "main" org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Err
or creating bean with name 'httpServiceClient': Injection of autowired dependencies fai
led; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could
not autowire field: com.vmware.vchs.networkservice.monitoring.JMXAgent com.vmware.vchs.
networkservice.extensions.http.HttpServiceClient.jmxAgent; nested exception is org.spri
ngframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [co
m.vmware.vchs.networkservice.monitoring.JMXAgent] found for dependency: expected at lea
st 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotat
ions: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
```

Comment: I'm assuming it's a web app, can you post `web.xml` file (if you have one) and the xml that contains that `component-scan`?

Comment: @AndreiStefan: Added the xml file

Comment: You need to write @Autowired before the declaration of JMXAgent

Comment: @SamwiseGamgee: Sorry I forgot to add in question description. But I added that in the code and due to that only it could not able to autowire that field

Comment: what does your httpServiceClient do?

Comment: @SamwiseGamgee: It is the main class

Comment: Your exception says no bean found that means that spring can not find the bean for JMXAgent.

Comment: My program is reading from different xml. So that is the reason of not finding the bean

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My program is reading from different xml. So that is the reason of not finding the bean

Answer (score 0):

In order to [Automatically detecting classes and registering bean definitions](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/4.0.5.RELEASE/spring-framework-reference/html/beans.html#beans-scanning-autodetection) I usually use `context` not `bean`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans
    xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans 
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context 
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd">

  <context:component-scan base-package="org.example"/>

</beans>
```

**Update**

```
<context:component-scan base-package="com.vmware.vchs.networkservice"/>
<context:component-scan base-package="com.vmware.vchs.networkservice.extensions.http"/>
```